# regex to extract non constant characters from a string

Tags: python, regex

How to extract non constant characters from a string using regex. String is

> archives/latest/pipelines/**my-page**/pages/**content/page1/**,

here i have to **remove** '*archives/latest/pipelines*' and  '*pages/*', which repeats in multiple strings

i have extracted **my-page** using below regex

```
(?<=archives\/latest\/pipelines\/)[^\/]*(?=\/pages\/)
```

but not sure how to extract **/my-page/content/page1/**

```
i/p : archives/latest/pipelines/my-page/pages/content/page1/
o/p : /my-page/content/page1/
```

please help

Comment: Can't you replace `archives/latest/pipelines/|pages/` with the empty string ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrsex7/1))?

Comment: will fail for these `archives/latest/pipelines/my-page/pages/content/pages/`

Comment: Can `pages/` also appear in the first variable part? In this case, how do you distinguish which one must be removed? For example, with `archives/latest/pipelines/1/pages/2/pages/3/pages/4/` do you want the first or second `pages/` to be removed? Please update your question claryfing this aspect.

Comment: it will always be `archives/latest/pipelines/*****/pages/`, want to remove the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
archives/latest/pipelines/([^/]*/)pages/(.*)
```

(where `[^/]*` means any number of characters different from `/`), then extract the first and second [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and concatenate them.

```py
>>> import re
>>> src = re.search(r"archives/latest/pipelines/([^/]*/)pages/(.*)", "archives/latest/pipelines/my-page/pages/content/page1/")
>>> src.group(1) + src.group(2)
'my-page/content/page1/'
```